# Store iOS device token to a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, ios, apple-push-notifications

I would like to get ready for production with APNS, and I am assuming the best (only, easiest?) way is to store the device IDs that sign up for push in a database (assuming SQL) and then having the PHP script (somehow?) send it to all of them (for loop?) instead of just one (`deviceToken` - mine)like I have now.

This is what I currently have in my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@“Token: %@", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

So here I am just logging the users deviceToken, and then I manually copied and pasted that into my PHP script which goes something like this:

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '[device token here]';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '[passphrase here]';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Hello, there!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

So what I need help with is making a connection to my server's database (MySQL) and storing the `deviceToken`. Then I need to loop the PHP into sending the notification to all the devices.

Let me know if I need to clarify on anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For storing device token in your MySQL database, you must create a seperate API.

For Ex. calling http://example.com/saveDeviceToken with device token.

At the time notification registration(didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken), you must call this API with parameter as your device token.

In this API you can fetch the device token and save it to your database.
Then in your above code you just fetch the device token from your DB.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I understand the bit about calling the API with the deviceToken I am currently logging as the parameter, but what I don't understand is the first part about actually creating the separate API, what would this file look like, how would this process change what code I am using in the PHP file I posted. Right now, I understand I need a separate API (which I don't know how to create or what it would include) to add the token to a database, and that I would need to call this from the app.

Comment: it's a simple thing. create another php file for saving input data to the database in your server. now from the mobile, just call this url with your device token. in your posted code, fetch $deviceToken from your db

Comment: Okay starting to understand. The new API will just be a PHP file with a parameter that stores the value into my database, and the app will call this when it gets the deviceToken.

Comment: How do I fetch $deviceToken from my database in PHP, new to this.

Comment: yeah you understood it well

Comment: it's not a prob. use the php code to fetch the device tokens from your  db and assigned that into $deviceToken

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55883/discussion-between-manujmv-and-isa-ranjha).